# Eviction and sorted sets in Redis

Tags: redis

How does key/value pair eviction impact the entries in a Redis sorted set? Does the various eviction policies remove entries from sorted sets?

I want to load a SKU of a product sorted set as well as the category of the product included in the key. The value of the product will also be included in the key. I want to be able to query the set and get back a filtered result for a certain category and price range.

How do I know if entries from the sorted set have been evicted since the initial load of the product catalog data? Missing products from the sorted set could lead to incorrect search results.

Answer (score 3):

Sorted sets do not expire individual entries.  Either the whole sorted set is expired or evicted or the whole set stays.

For what you are looking at - you may want to try [Redisearch](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/)

Comment: Thanks @namizaru, I’m assuming the behavior of a eviction of the set would result in a future ZRANGE failing due to missing set. I’m assuming ZRANGE error will represent this. Then in this scenario it would be up to the client to rebuild the set. Is this correct?